# error C2371, redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c

I get the error code c2371, for the functions; seperate, longest and shortest. I think its about the input arguments.

```
error C2371: 'seperate' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2371: 'shortest' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2371: 'longest' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char msg[41];
  int selector = 0;

  printf("Alinur Caglayan - 18050127622 - Lab Work 5 ");
  printf("Please enter a string message with maximum of 40 characters: ");
  gets(msg);

  printf("Please select one of the following functions:\n1) Longest Word Function");
  printf("\n2) Shortest Word Function\n3) Separate Words Function\n4) Exit: ");
  scanf("%d", &selector);

  if(selector == 1)
  {
    longest(msg);
  }
  else if(selector == 2)
  {
    shortest();
  }
  else if(selector == 3)
  {
    seperate();
  }
  else if(selector == 4)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\nPlease enter a valid integer!\n");
    scanf("%d", selector);
  }
}

char longest(msg)
{
  char *temp = msg, *word = msg, *max = msg;
  int increment = 0, incrementmax = 0;

  do {
    if(!(*temp & ~32)) 
    {
      if(increment > incrementmax) 
      {
        incrementmax = increment;
        max = word;
      }
      increment = 0;
    } 
    else if(!increment++) 
    {
      word = temp;
    }
  } 
  while(*temp++ != 0);

  for(temp = max; (*temp & ~32); ) 
  {
    printf("%c", *temp++);
  }
}

char shortest(msg)
{
  char *temp = msg, *word = msg, *max = msg;
  int increment = 0, incrementmax = 0;

  do {

    if(!(*temp & ~32)) 
    {

      if(increment > incrementmax) 
      {
        incrementmax = increment;
        max = word;
      }
      increment = 0;
    } 
    else if(!increment++)
    {
      word = temp; 
    }
  } 
  while(*temp++ != 0);

  for(temp = max; (*temp & ~32); ) 
  {
    printf("%c", *temp++);
  }
}

char seperate(msg)
{

  char *temp = msg;
  int i;

  printf("Alinur Caglayan - 18050127622 - Lab Work 5 ");
  printf("Please enter a string message with maximum of 40 characters: ");
  gets(msg);

  for(i=0; i < 41; i++)
  {
    if(*temp & ~32)
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%c", temp);
    }
    system("pause");
  }
}
```

Comment: bad c will cost you a foot.

Comment: The functions are implicitly declared to return `int` when they're used.  When you later redefine them to return `char`, you get the error you're seeing.  Declare all functions before they're used; its the standard way (meaning C99 and C11 standard C require that).

Comment: function prototype put on before main.

Comment: Never use `gets()`.  **Never** use `gets()`.  It is *impossible* to use safely.

Comment: this code should have raised several other warnings/errors.  does the compile have all warnings enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your functions without first declaring their types. This is not allowed in the two latest versions of the C standard, and should result in a diagnostic message.

However, if your compiler complies with an older standard (or none at all), calling an undeclared function will cause the compiler to provide its own declaration with a return type that defaults to `int`. When you later define the functions to have a different return type, the compiler warns you about the mismatch.

You should always declare your functions (i.e. the return type and the types of its parameters), *or* in trivial cases, define your functions (i.e. with function body) before you call them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors.

You should declare your functions before main like this:

```
char shortest(char msg[41]);
char longest(char msg[41]);
```

or if you don't want to declare them you could define them before main...

Also you have a:

```
scanf("%d", selector);
```

While it should be:

```
scanf("%d", &selector);
```

And all your functioncs should return a char too.

**Edited:** Another thing is that you define your functions like:

```
char longest(msg) {
    ...
}
```

But you have to specify the type of the argument, like this.

```
char longest(char msg[41]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following only corrects the basic syntax, without looking into what that sub functions are actually doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// prototypes
void longest ( char * );
void shortest( char * );
void seperate( char * );

int main(void)
{
    char msg[41];
    int selector = 0;

    printf("Alinur Caglayan - 18050127622 - Lab Work 5 ");
    printf("Please enter a string message with maximum of 40 characters: ");
    if( NULL == fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin) )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int done = 0; // indicate not done

    while(!done)
    { 
        printf("Please select one of the following functions:\n");
        printf( "1) Longest Word Function\n");
        printf( "2) Shortest Word Function\n");
        printf( "3) Separate Words Function\n");
        printf( "4) Exit:\n");

        if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &selector) )
        {
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        } 

        switch( selector )
        {
            case 1:
                longest(msg);
                break;

            case 2:
                shortest(msg);
                break;

            case 3:
                seperate(msg);
                break;

            case 4:
                done = 1; // cause loop to exit
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nERROR: invalid selection entered\n");
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end while

    return(0);
} // end funtion: main


void longest( char* msg)
{
    char *temp = msg, *word = msg, *max = msg;
    int increment = 0, incrementmax = 0;

    do {
        if(!(*temp & ~32)) 
        {
            if(increment > incrementmax) 
            {
                incrementmax = increment;
                max = word;
            } // end if

            increment = 0;
        }

        else if(!increment++) 
        {
            word = temp;
        } // end if
    } while(*temp++ != 0);

    for(temp = max; (*temp & ~32); ) 
    {
    printf("%c", *temp++);
    }
} // end function: longest

void shortest(char* msg)
{
    char *temp = msg, *word = msg, *max = msg;
    int increment = 0, incrementmax = 0;

    do {

        if(!(*temp & ~32)) 
        {

            if(increment > incrementmax) 
            {
                incrementmax = increment;
                max = word;
            } // end if
            increment = 0;
        }

        else if(!increment++)
        {
            word = temp; 
        }
    } while(*temp++ != 0);

    for(temp = max; (*temp & ~32); temp++) 
    {
        printf("%c", *temp);
    }
} // end function: shortest

void seperate(char* msg)
{

    char *temp = msg;
    int i;

    printf("Alinur Caglayan - 18050127622 - Lab Work 5 ");
    printf("Please enter a string message with maximum of 40 characters: ");
    if( NULL == fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin) )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for(i=0; i < 41; i++)
    {
        if(*temp & ~32)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", temp);
        }  // end if

        system("pause");
    } // end for
} // end function: seperate
```